# knockout template binding not working fully

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-templating

I am using javascript template with knockout.

`<div data-bind="template: { name: 'treeElement', foreach: results }`">'

```
<script type=text/html>
 <!--ko if: a>b -->
    <div data-bind={textcontent:a}/>`
<!--/ko-->
</script>
```

something like above.. I am geting displayed div element with textcontetn with value of a however containerless binding is not getting applied.. a>b is not calculating. so its just ignoring  syntax..

Comment: I dont think the container less binding can be the first node.  Try wrapping it in a div

Comment: @PWKad i have shown here only for example.. it is wrapped in div tag in my real code..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a jsFiddle to repro the issue to help with identifying problems with it.

Comment: That template isn't even named. How else do you expect to use if if you don't even reference it?

Comment: @JeffMercado i have given id to script in my real code.. asssume it is there. template is getting generated there and value is also getting displayed.. only not working is if and not if conditions..

Comment: "something like above.. " .. is it something like this or is it exactly this? post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

- When you are writing the name of properties like that in comment binding
  you need to execute them in order to resolve them to their result as
  currently you are simply comparing two functions.
- Furthermore your markup is invalid as both of your div tags are not
  closed and end with a wired single quote which makes bindings fail.
- There is such binding in knockout known as `textcontent`.

If you change your html to:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'treeElement', foreach: results }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="treeElement">
 <!--ko if: a() > b() -->
    <div data-bind="text: a() + ' is bigger than ' + b()"/></div>
 <!--/ko-->
</script>
```

and we assume you have a view model similar to my construct of your scenario which is:

```
var treeElements = [
    {"a" : 2 , "b" : 1},
    {"a" : 4 , "b" : 6},
    {"a" : 9 , "b" : 5},
    {"a" : 2 , "b" : 7},
    {"a" : 4 , "b" : 9},
]

function treeElement(data){
    this.a = ko.observable(data.a);
    this.b = ko.observable(data.b);
}

function viewmodel(){
    var self = this;
    self.results = ko.observableArray();
    self.init = function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(treeElements, function(item){
            self.results.push(new treeElement(item));
        });
    }
}

var myVM = new viewmodel();
myVM.init();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

You should be good to go.

[Here is also a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpeLX/9/)

Comment: in my code everything is working fine. only nt working is ko if and ifnot conditions.. even those conditions are working on browsers.. i m trying it on windows store javascript app. windows 8.1